# Need help formatting Bootstrap 3 and HTML to keep textbox in middle of well when browser resized

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got my login objects, username and password and login button inside a transparent well

My problem is I have tried everything to stop the username and password textboxes from jumping to left side of the well when the browser's width is reduced. Strangely the 'remember me', logo and login button stay in the middle as i want

this can be seen at the site https://www.ascsol.co.uk/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F

just narrow the browser and watch the username and password field auto left justify

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="well well-lg">

                <img class="img-rounded" width="279" height="54" src="~/content/images/EdgeLogoBig.jpg" />

                <br />

                @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    if (!Html.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            @Html.ValidationSummary(true,"Invalid username and/or password")
                        </div>
                    }

                    <div class="form-group">

                        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Username", autocomplete = "off" })

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">

                        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">

                            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Password", autocomplete = "off" })


                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
                            <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-success btn-flat" />

                        </div>
                    </div>


                }
            </div>


        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: THe use of col-sm-* and col-xs-* should help. See : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Your input text-boxes size keep on changing during re-size, initially size its smaller and on reducing window width their size increases,not looking good UX to me, is this intentional ? If not then set some width on them instead of width:100% and display:block

Answer (score 0):

**Solved:**

Why are you setting class 'col-sm-offset-3' inside 'form-group' container, when you resize the window to smaller size the margin-left of 'col-sm-offset-3' becomes zero and your controls move to left.
I guess you have added them to center align your content.

**# Approach:** From your class 'form-control' remove `display:block` or change it to `display: inline-block;` . On re-sizing window your text-box will now stay in center.

For aligning checkbox to center, add below css classes

```
.checkbox{ 
text-align: center;
}
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
float: none;
}
```

I have tested this fix on your site using firebug and it seems to solve your problem.